# R - change factor to variable

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, dataformat

I do have a question regarding my data format that I didn't find in any of the posts here.

Currently, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> bymonth
       month n_positive n_negative 
1      April        563        587
2     August        186        240
3   December        671        581
4   February       2026       1827
5    January       1227       1115
6       July         63         57
7       June        360        336
8      March        430        378
9        May        422        481
10  November       1017        947
11   October        617        694
12 September        601        434
```

I would like to create a time series with the month names as variables. Something that looks like this:

```
> bymonth
   sentiment    January   February    March   April  ...
1 n_positive       1227       2026      430     563  ...
2 n_negative       1115       1827      378     587  ...
```

How can I do this? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You just want to transpose your data?

```
t(bymonth)
```

Comment: Correct, I would add a couple of lines to turn the result into data.frame with correct col names, sentiment column etc... e.g. : `m=as.data.frame(t(DF[,-1]));colnames(m)=DF$month;m=cbind(sentiment=row.names(m),m)`

Comment: Thanks guys! That helped a lot!